# Dynamically display images on vue front end from api

Tags: vue.js, strapi

I am trying to display an image dynamically based on the path given from an api call. All the other data is displaying correctly, but not the image. I suspect that I am not inputting the correct path. The front end is in a folder called `client` and the images are in a subdirectory of the `cms` folder, which is in the same directory as `client`.

Frontend: root/client/src/components/Arrangements.vue

Images: root/cms/public/uploads/some-image.png

Here is my code:

Template

```html
    <div v-if="arrangements.length">
        <div :key="arrangement.index" v-for="arrangement in arrangements">
            <img :src="getImages(arrangement.img.formats.thumbnail.url)" alt="">
            <p>{{ `${arrangement.title}` }}</p>
            <p>{{ `$${arrangement.price}` }}</p>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Script

```js
    import axios from "axios";
    
    export default {
        data() {
            return {
                arrangements: []
            }
        },
        mounted() {
            axios.get("http://localhost:1337/arrangements")
                .then(res => {
                    this.arrangements = res.data;
                })
                .catch(error => {
                    this.error = error;
                })
        },
        methods: {
            getImages(url) {
                return '/cms/public' + url;
            }
        }
    }
```

API Call

[image]

EDIT:

Project Structure

My front end code where I am trying to access the images is `Arrangements.vue`, while the images are in `cms/public/uploads`

[image]

Comment: What does the image src look like, when inspecting the element in the developer console? Do you get 404 errors in the network tab?

Comment: The image src is "/cms/public/uploads/imgurl.png" so it's what I expect. I'll have to check for 404 in the network tab when I get home.

Comment: I think your src should be relative, starting with '../'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use require to get images. Try this way.

In your case you can use this way.

```
 getImages(url) {
      return require('../../../cms/public/' + url);
  }
```

Note: I'm considering that your image path is correct. I'm used to use the variable @ to access the assets folder, something like that:

```
<img :src="require('@/assets/img/my_image.png')" />
```

Comment: Anytime I use `require`, I get `Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '/cms' in 'C:\Users\reaga\Desktop\Projects\fly-away-garden\client\src\components'`

Comment: Can you post your project structure?

Comment: Check my edit to see the project structure

Comment: :src="require(`../../../cms/public/${your_file_here}`);

Comment: Wow, thank you so much. I tried this earlier but with one less `../`. I forgot to go up one more level!

Answer (score 0):

try this one

```
computed：{
 getImages(){
  var filename = this.arrangements
  return require(`/cms/public/${fileName}.png`);
 }
}
```

You have to put it inside computed so it will be reload the images when the images path come in and then bind it with :src="getImages".

Comment: Like I said to Vinicius' post below, I am getting `Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '/cms' in 'C:\Users\reaga\Desktop\Projects\fly-away-garden\client\src\components'` when using `require`